# Extending react hook useState for use in event handlers

Tags: react.js, typescript

I use React with material-ui.com and I love them both, but I'm tired with writing the boilerplate handlers like

```
onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setEmail(e.currentTarget.value)}
```

again and again. Especially when `stopPropagation` is needed (AFAICT it's always either needed or harmless), it gets pretty verbose.

So I tried to extend `useState` so that it provides everything I need, so I can write things like:

```
const [email, setEmail, emailAgg] = useStateEx('');
...
onChange={emailAgg.changeHandler}
```

or

```
const [showPassword, , showPasswordAgg] = useStateEx(false);
...
onClick={showPasswordAgg.toggleHandler}
```

and similar.

---

My approach follows. I'd like it to be reviewed in general, especially for better typing (I had to use `@ts-ignore`) and improvements.

I case you hate semicolons, please ignore them as my eslint is set up to require them. ;)

```
import { useState, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

function booleanAgg(value: boolean, setter: (value: boolean) => void, makeSetter: (value: boolean) => ((event?: any) => void)) {
    return {
        value,
        setter,
        falseHandler: makeSetter(false),
        trueHandler: makeSetter(true),
        toggleHandler: makeSetter(!value),
    };
}

function stringAgg(value: string, setter: (value: string) => void) {
    return {
        value,
        setter,
        changeHandler: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement|HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            setter(e.currentTarget.value);
        }
    };
}

function numberAgg(value: number, setter: (value: number) => void) {
    return {
        value,
        setter,
        changeHandler: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement|HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            setter(+e.currentTarget.value);
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Works like useState and adds a third element containing boolean-specific handlers directly useable in buttons and checkboxes.
 */
export function useStateEx(initialState: boolean) : [boolean, Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>, ReturnType<typeof booleanAgg>];

/**
 * Works like useState and adds a third element containing string-specific handlers directly useable in text fields.
 */
export function useStateEx(initialState: string) : [string, Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>, ReturnType<typeof stringAgg>];

/**
 * Works like useState and adds a third element containing number-specific handlers directly useable in text fields.
 */
export function useStateEx(initialState: number) : [number, Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>, ReturnType<typeof numberAgg>];

/**
 * Prohibits use with any type not handled in the above overloads.
 */
export function useStateEx(initialState: any) : never;

export function useStateEx<S extends boolean|string|number>(initialState: S) : unknown {
    const [value, setter] = useState(initialState);
    function makeSetter(value: S) {
        return function(e: any) {
            if (typeof e?.stopPropagation === 'function') e.stopPropagation();
            setter(value);
        };
    }
    if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
        // @ts-ignore
        return [value, setter, booleanAgg(value, setter, makeSetter)]
    } else if (typeof value === 'string') {
        // @ts-ignore
        return [value, setter, stringAgg(value, setter)];
    } else if (typeof value === 'number') {
        // @ts-ignore
        return [value, setter, numberAgg(value, setter)];
    } else {
        throw new Error('Only boolean, string and number is supported');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I must admit that my experience with [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) and [react.js](/questions/tagged/react.js) is quite limited so my review will be limited to basic syntax points. This code seems straight-forward. It makes good use of arrow functions and destruction assignment. There are just a couple suggestions I will make below.

> ```
> if (typeof e?.stopPropagation === 'function') e.stopPropagation();
> ```

It is best to include brackets around the block, even if it is all on one line:

```
if (typeof e?.stopPropagation === 'function') { e.stopPropagation(); }
```

Some believe such blocks should never be on one line. If you are going to do it on one line, you could use short-circuiting:

```
typeof e?.stopPropagation === 'function' && e.stopPropagation();
```

---

This block can be simplified somewhat:

> ```
> if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
>     // @ts-ignore
>     return [value, setter, booleanAgg(value, setter, makeSetter)]
> } else if (typeof value === 'string') {
>     // @ts-ignore
>     return [value, setter, stringAgg(value, setter)];
> } else if (typeof value === 'number') {
>     // @ts-ignore
>     return [value, setter, numberAgg(value, setter)];
> } else {
>     throw new Error('Only boolean, string and number is supported');
> }
> ```

The `else` keywords can be avoided because preceding blocks have `return` statements.'

```
if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
    // @ts-ignore
    return [value, setter, booleanAgg(value, setter, makeSetter)]
} 
if (typeof value === 'string') {
    // @ts-ignore
    return [value, setter, stringAgg(value, setter)];
} 
if (typeof value === 'number') {
    // @ts-ignore
    return [value, setter, numberAgg(value, setter)];
}
throw new Error('Only boolean, string and number is supported');
```